# Backup via ZFS snapshot/clone with adjusted filesystem permissions

Tags: backup, zfs

ZFS snapshots are great for rolling backups. Say, we have `tank/home` mounted at `/home`. Then a simple `zfs snapshot tank/home@TIMESTAMP` will give a backup accessible at `/home/.zfs/snapshot/TIMESTAMP`. However, there is a problem when a user set too lax permissions on some file and corrects this error only after the snapshot has been made. The file will still be readable by the wrong people in the snapshot, and all the user can do is wait until the snapshot is destroyed (which happens via cron job as a part of the rolling backup scheme).

A simple `chmod go-rwx /home/.zfs/snapshot/TIMESTAMP/*` would help, but snapshots are read-only. I came up with the following solution:

```
chmod o-rwx /home/.zfs/snapshot
zfs snapshot tank/home@snap-TIMESTAMP
zfs clone tank/home@snap-TIMESTAMP tank/clone-TIMESTAMP
zfs set mountpoint=/root/tmp tank/clone-TIMESTAMP
chmod go-rwx /root/tmp/*
zfs set readonly=on tank/clone-TIMESTAMP
zfs set mountpoint=/backup/TIMESTAMP tank/clone-TIMESTAMP
```

Now the backup can be accessed in a read-only manner by users at `/backup/TIMESTAMP`, and it has the modified permissions.

At least one problem with this is that the permissions on `/home/.zfs/snapshot` will be back to world-readable after a reboot. Can this behavior be changed? We cannot destroy the snapshot, since the clone depends on it.

A much simpler solution is, of course, to store the current permissions of the home directories, then run `chmod go-rwx /home/*`, take the snapshot, and finally restore the permissions. This brings a number of race conditions, though.

Any better ideas?

**Addendum:** I have now settled for one dataset per user. So each user has her snapshots in `~/.zfs/snapshot`. This is not a 100% solution. If a user has `0701` on her home directory, e.g., to make `~/public_html` work, then still an attacker can read a file in a snapshot which had the wrong permissions at the time when the snapshot was taken. However, at least the user can now "pull the plug" in an emergency by making her home directory `0700`.

Changing ownership and permissions of each `~/.zfs` would be a better solution, but such changes do not survive a reboot. The appropriate chowns and chmods could be run at startup, but this needs to be implemented carefully in order not to create a short period in which files are still exposed.

Comment: Have you considered using a separate dataset for each user's home directory?

Comment: @MichaelHampton Yes, I did, but thought it was crazy. Now thinking again, I feel it is probably the best way to go. It would also have the benefit that users can pick up their backups from `~/.zfs/snapshot` and do not have to navigate to `/home/.zfs/snapshot`.

Comment: Let me emphasize one thing first: **ZFS snapshots are not backups.** Anyhow, if you are using the [OpenZFS](https://OpenZFS.org/) implementation of ZFS, this issue has been (and still is) discussed on the [GitHub](https://GitHub.com/openzfs/zfs/discussions/9028) (see [issue #3963](https://GitHub.com/openzfs/zfs/issues/3963) to track progress). There is also a [FreeBSD issue](https://bugs.FreeBSD.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=265625) (FreeBSD adopted OpenZFS in version 13.0).

Answer (score 1):

In ZFS, snapshots are immutable: you cannot alter any file properties after the snapshot was taken.

You can try  to `chmod` the snapshot directory (or the .zfs directory) itself. Or, taking another approach, you can set `snapdir=hidden`

Comment: I think `snapdir=hidden` will only hide the directory from `ls`, but will not forbid access.

Comment: @LasseKliemann Sure, but depending on your specific needs, maybe it can be sufficient